# Protecting routes in Next.js using middleware

Tags: next.js

I'm trying to protect my routes in my Next.js 13.4 app using the middleware, I'm using the new app directory, the problem I'm facing is with redirecting users according to the token , if there is a token then we redirect him to the homepage if there is no token we redirect him to the login page, it is telling me **localhost redirected you too many times.** I can't understand where the problem lies and how to fix, I have searched a lot and can't figure how to solve the error, if someone can help me fix this issue would be great

The route to the homepage is "/"

The route to the login page is "/auth/login"

Keep in mind that I'm using group routes **(root)** is where the main layout of the application is and **(auth)** is the layout of all authentications.

This is the middleware that I have written :

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export default async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
const path = req.nextUrl.pathname;
const authToken = req.cookies.get("OurSiteJWT");
console.log(authToken)
if (authToken) {
return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/", req.url));
} 
else if (!authToken) {
// return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/auth/login", req.url));
return null;
}
return NextResponse.next();
}

export const config = {
matcher: ["/auth/login", "/:path*"]
}
```